# Association with sonar plugin...empty group ID

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I am trying to use snore plugin for analyzing my code.
1- I did install the Plug in.
2- I did install the server and it is connected

as the instruction in the documentation .. I did association but it did not link to the sonar server.

I do not why.. beside it does not show in the filter of the association the group ID..

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Sonar+in+Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you read carefully the document, you must first run a Sonar analysis of your project so that it is displayed in Sonar Web application. Then only you'll be able to associate it in Eclipse.

To sum up:

1. First you run "mvn clean install" and "mvn sonar:sonar" in a shell
2. Then you check that you can browse the project in a browser
3. Lastly you can try to associate it in Eclipse

Comment: Installing mvn was done correctly . when I try to execute the "mvn sonar:sonar" ... I had an error .. it says no pom.

Comment: I do not what exactly the pom file ... is it the one that comes when I tried to convert my java project to mvn project.. I tried to redirect to the pom in for that project .. but it did not work.

Comment: Error Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:20.0::sonar

Comment: Everything is described in the documentation: please take time to read it before asking trivial questions => http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code